# How to remove lock if workspace does not exist in terraform?

Tags: terraform

While applying my terraform changes I get the following error:

```
failed to lock s3 state: ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed
Lock Info:
  ID:        4ec40fb6-3e1c-e28a-f2ea-c888884f13d6
  Path:      terraform-backend/env:/272989/amtr/terraform
  Operation: OperationTypeApply
  Who:       root@runner-d8-yafp--project-1791-concurrent-0dgbm7
  Version:   1.4.4
  Created:   2023-06-13 19:15:16.397237308 +0000 UTC
  Info:      
Workspace "272989" doesn't exist.
```

When I checked the s3 path `terraform-backend/env:/272989/amtr/terraform`, it does not exist as `272989` workspace is deleted. It also stop me from creating this workspace. How can I remove the lock in this case ?

Comment: Hey! Have you tried terraform's built-in manual unlock? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/force-unlock
`terraform force-unlock 4ec40fb6-3e1c-e28a-f2ea-c888884f13d6`